# Is it grammatical to use a comparative form with a definite article?

Tags: comparative

A: Whose book is this? Yours?
B: Oh, it's Mark's. Mine is -----.

I know * Mine is thinner.* is correct.
How about *Mine is the thinner.*
Is it grammatical to add the article?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: as in 'the thinner book often contains less words.'? yes it is.

Comment: In this type of usage, you would usually say, "Mine is the thinner one".

Answer (score 2):

You *can* say *"Mine is the thinner."* It is uncommon, and sounds a little poetic, but it isn't wrong, and would be universally understood by native speakers.

---

With superlatives, what you are proposing is more common.  I would have a hard time coming up with a general preference between the following three sentences:

> We both have thin cats, but... *mine is thinnest.  `[OR]`...mine is the thinnest one.  `[OR]`...mine is the thinnest.*

With comparatives, the three forms are all correct, but the first two are more common:

> We both have thin cats.  *Mine is thinner. `[OR]` Mine is the thinner one.*  <--More common
>
> We both have thin cats. *Mine is the thinner.*  <-- Less common, but acceptable.

With absolutes, however, you can't use all three of those constructions

> We both have cats.  *Mine is thin. `[OR]` Mine is the thin one.*  <---Fine
>
> We both have cats.  *Mine is the thin.*  <--  NOT OK

Answer (score 0):

Satnam has the answer here.  Generally you would put an object after the adjective.  "Mine is the thinner one."  would be the best way of expressing the idea.